# php file_put_contents asian character filename encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm trying to get this scrape images off of wikipedia. What good is *free licensed media* if you can't get it? Original script is [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User%3aWikiLaurent/ScrapCCAnimScript).

If you put this

> http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/%E7%9A%84-bw.png

in firefox, it will immediately be transformed into

> http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/的-bw.png

so that when you save the image, it's saved as 的-bw.png

Simple enough eh? Now how to get php to do that? Just guessing, I tried utf8_decode($fileName) .. but getting the wrong Chinese characters.

```
$src= "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/%E7%9A%84-bw.png";  
$pngData = file_get_contents($src);  
$fileName = basename($src);  
file_put_contents($fileName, $pngData);
```

Any help appreciated, as I really have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `url_decode();` ?

```
<?php
$url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/%E7%9A%84-bw.png';
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$title = $parts[count($parts)-1]; //get last section

$title = urldecode($title);
?>
```

Comment: brr.. yes, tried that, still getting the wrong character. I copy the url from $src, paste into firefox and I get the file with correct filename. With php I get the same file alright, but with a different filename, another Chinese character. Updated the question..

Comment: come to think about it, i think you've answered my question. at least point me in the right direction. I'll rephrase the question and post a new one.. **it's urldecode() instead of url_decode(); by the way**

Comment: So what I would do is get the section with the title in it, then run urldecode on that section. Check the edited code above (not sure if it will work, isn't tested.  Then make sure you use utf8 or something similar so that the characters don't get mixed up with ascii characters

Comment: Thanks, tried that, still same problem. First I thought the problem was with file_put_contents not being able to write files with the passed filename.. now I see it's returning the decoding part that's going haywire.. I check this further

Answer (score 0):

Squirrelmail contains a nice function in the sources to convert unicode to entities:

```
<?php 
function charset_decode_utf_8 ($string) { 
       /* Only do the slow convert if there are 8-bit characters */ 
     /* avoid using 0xA0 (\240) in ereg ranges. RH73 does not like that */ 
     if (! ereg("[\200-\237]", $string) and ! ereg("[\241-\377]", $string)) 
         return $string; 

     // decode three byte unicode characters 
     $string = preg_replace("/([\340-\357])([\200-\277])([\200-\277])/e",        
     "'&#'.((ord('\\1')-224)*4096 + (ord('\\2')-128)*64 + (ord('\\3')-128)).';'",    
     $string); 

     // decode two byte unicode characters 
     $string = preg_replace("/([\300-\337])([\200-\277])/e", 
     "'&#'.((ord('\\1')-192)*64+(ord('\\2')-128)).';'", 
     $string); 

     return $string; 
 } 
?>
```

Comment: thanks for that. Tried it, returns same character as urldecode above.